# Generating xml from mysql database using JSP

Tags: mysql, xml, jsp

I want to generate xml from database using JSP. I found a [link](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/16866-JSP-and-XML-.data-store-nd-retrieve.html)  which generate xml file from a  form but i want to genarate it using mysql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can generate XML from a MySQL database is by writing a stored procedure. There an interesting article [here](http://eriksdiary.blogspot.com/2007/07/xml-output-from-mysql.html) that shows how it can be done.